# Dual screen eligiblity

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors

Given I am running ubuntu 10.10 with the following configuration, do you think I am eligible for a dual screen setup?

> Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
>
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
>
> 00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics  Controller (rev 03)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical/general constraint is going to be if you have two video ports on your machine. If you do, then yes, that's generally very easily done.

If you don't, you may be able to add/upgrade your video system to something that does. Any PCI-E Video card you buy new today, will support two monitors - the crappiest of those can be picked up for in the $30 range.

A final semi-option is you can get any number of weird adapters that can let you drive multiple monitors in various ways. [These](http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10104), for example, let you split a single video signal on to multiple screens. There are also weird things out there like "USB montitors", that you plugin over USB - I've never tried one as that concept sounds like a horrible idea to me - but I've seen some of that gear around.

So really, **yes, you are eligible, unless you don't have two video ports, are unwilling to buy upgrade hardware or have a severely crummy old machine.**

As for how well it'll run, I suppose that wasn't really the question - but it'll be a function of the total resolution, color depth and some other similar parameters, but it should generally be fine for non-opengl applications.

Comment: If you want a more specific answer, then please provide more detail. Such as a picture of the back of your computer, make & model number, photo of your motherboard, etc..

Comment: Thanks. On the connectivity side, since I don't have two video ports on my machine I was thinking more about what you called a 'semi-option' -- an adapter. I thought the type of graphic card would matter also hence the config that I posted on my question.

Comment: What you have doesn't matter much, it's more what your motherboard will support. Do you know the make and model of your motherboard?